# Accessing iframe context with Electron

Tags: javascript, iframe, electron

I have an Electron app where I load external sites into a `BrowswerView` hosted in a `BrowserWindow`. Invariably each site has a video player on it using a `<video>` tag. Normally you can access the DOM using `executeJavaScript` and do things like this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('video').forEach(input => { input.pause() })
```

This would pause all the playing video on the site.
Problem is, one particular pesky site loads the video player into an iframe that is in a different sub domain.

Enter CORS. I cannot get to the video container without hitting the dreaded `Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.whatever.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.`

Here is my question: In the chrome dev tools you can select the context from a drop down so clearly it is possible to choose the context from the client. As I am running this in Electron I would like to believe that there is a way to switch contexts. I am not looking to run the code cross origin but directly in the frame I just need a way to choose it.

I looked at `mainFrame.frames` but I don't see how you get to the sub frame's `webContents`.

Any clues on this?

Answer (score 0):

I basically rubber ducky'd this thing. After typing this up, I figured it out.
I looked at the instance methods again and saw that executeJavascript is one of them so I don't need to get to `webContents` at all...

So this works and I thought I would share:

```
view.webContents.mainFrame.frames.forEach(frame => {
  const url = new URL(frame.url)
  if (url.host === 'sub.whatever.com') {
    frame.executeJavaScript('myCodeHere')
  }
})
```

I used the host name in my instance but you could use `frame.processId` instead.